# Performing experiments to optimize revenue from pages with AdSense ads

Tags: google-adsense, revenue

Let's say I have a page with several AdSense ads. If I will do any A-B testing of different page layouts, ads sizes and so on it would be very nice to have an ability to add a channel information to the ads code on the fly (with no visit to AdSense control panel and manualy creating of new ads associated with a new channel for each experiment).

As I can see from the AdSense ads code and the control pannel interface - I have no such possibility.

But it looks a bit frustrating as Google itself engaging us to perform experiments as much as possible but it looks like Google not giving us proper tools for this thing. So I'm sure that I'm just not informed well.

I'd make it in the following way: add a additional parameter to AdSense code (something like data-ad-chan="123") to be able to filter the data by this parameter later on.

The AdSense Experiments section really not looks like the thing I need as it is not giving me the ability to perform the page layout changing.

Answer (score 1):

[AdSense does allow custom channels](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/65083?hl=en) but they can't be set on the ads by the website.  The only way to change the channels is through the AdSense website.

It is possible to duplicate all your ads in the AdSense interface.   Add the "TestGroupA" channel to the originals and add the "TestGroupB" channel to the new ones.  Then your server could choose which ad code to show based on which test group the user is in.

Comment: I will need to manually capture the code for each new channel?

Comment: You need to manually create the code for each new channel.

Comment: that's nightmare :)